# How to convert Hexadecimal Byte stream in the form of string to actual bytestream in javascript?

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation

I have a pdf file that is available in the form of a Hexa string bytestream like:

```
"255044462D312E330D0A25E2E3CFD30D0A322030206F626A......"
```

(its a very long string, so I have just given the format)
which is in a string format available in the browser.

I need to convert this into its hexadecimal format so that I can render the pdf in the web browser by writing this output stream to the pdf file. I need to know if there is any inbuilt function or any way this can be achieved in Javascript.

I know implementing this functionality is simple with Java but I have an `ABAP` backend that only fetches me this string and `SAPUI5` front end that is a framework based on Javascript.

I checked the validity this bytestream by writing a simple java program that generated the PDF just for testing purpose if the data is coming right:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  FileOutputStream fop = null;
  File file;
  file = new File("C:/Users/I074098/Desktop/Project Temps/test.pdf");
  fop = new FileOutputStream(file);
  // if file doesnt exists, then create it
  if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
  }
  //I manually added "(byte) 0x" in the above string and 
  //converted it to the following format, I skipped that conversion in this code
  byte[] contentInBytes = new byte[]{
    (byte) 0x25,(byte) 0x50,(byte) 0x44,(byte) 0x46, .....
  } 
  fop.write(contentInBytes);
    fop.flush();
    fop.close();
  }
```

This generates the pdf. But I know it is very inefficient and I am not sure all this can be done in javascript.
I have done a lot of search and it was not fruitful. I will be thankful any and every help.

Regards,
Riswan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   //  To IE Boat method is here,

        if (!window.btoa) {
    var tableStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
    var table = tableStr.split("");

    window.btoa = function (bin) {
    for (var i = 0, j = 0, len = bin.length / 3, base64 = []; i < len; ++i) {
    var a = bin.charCodeAt(j++), b = bin.charCodeAt(j++), c = bin.charCodeAt(j++);
    if ((a | b | c) > 255) throw new Error("String contains an invalid character");
    base64[base64.length] = table[a >> 2] + table[((a << 4) & 63) | (b >> 4)] +
    (isNaN(b) ? "=" : table[((b << 2) & 63) | (c >> 6)]) +
    (isNaN(b + c) ? "=" : table[c & 63]);
    }
    return base64.join("");
    };
    } 

      //script block
      // try this way  to open you pdf file like this in javascript hope it will help you.
        function hexToBase64(str)
          {
         return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,str.replace(/\r|\n/g, "").replace(/([\da-fA-F]{2}) ?/g, "0x$1 ").replace(/ +$/, "").split(" ")));
          }

          var data=   hexToBase64("255044462D312E330D0A25E2E3CFD30D0A322030206F626A");// here pass the big hex string

            // it will be open in the web browser like this
            document.location.href = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' +data;

     **//to open up in the new window**
    window.open('data:application/pdf;base64,' +data, "_blank", "directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no,width=600, height=280,top=200,left=200");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tamkeen! I owe you. It worked perfectly in all browsers other than IE. In IE btoa() is not recognised. And the pdf created is not downloadable (but I'm able to print). 
The pdf is displayed on the same page due to document.location.href.  I tried:
window.open( 'data:application/pdf;base64,' +binData ,'mywindow', 'location=0,titlebar=0,width=1000,height=600');
to open in a new window, but it was not working.
Any help on how can I make it downloadable and open in a new window by setting a title to it? Again my hearty thanks..

Comment: @riswan Answer updated  fro the ie boat method you need to add the a code block it will work now and for the download i don't know i have done that at server side not in javscript,it may possible to do that  you need to look into the response header ie   'Content-type', 'application/octet-stream'
'Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=filename.pdf'

Comment: and if u change the document.location.href = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' +data  to the document.location.href = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' +data u will get the downloadable  option but the thing is it will .part extension file not the pdf.

Comment: it may help you see this http://pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/test.html to save pdf or text files

Comment: Thanks again Tamkeen. Hex to Base 64 conversion is happening in IE with the method that you gave, but I am not able to display the pdf as I guess there is a limit on url length in IE and as the entire pdf is appended to the url, it is not getting displayed. Since IE is the primary browser used for testing my application, its a huge concern. I am able to open in a new window. I tried using "application/octet-stream" but it opens only an empty window. I am not sure if i can use Downloadify, but I will look into this.

Comment: i recommend you to make use of given link ,                       i think no other way to do that and **you put another query for that let other people help you make download** as you query concerns about the render the pdf in the web browser done right for IE  go with the link .

Comment: Thanks Tamkeen. I will create a new question.

Comment: fine if i find anything  surly help you :).

Comment: Thanks :) Here is the new question that I posted:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201209/creating-a-file-in-javascript-using-the-available-bytestream