# Creating a file in Javascript using the available Bytestream

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation

Is there any way to create a file (eg: a PDF) in JavaScript by setting its mime type, title, content, etc and display it in the browser with the option to download?

I have a Base64 bytestream of a pdf in the javascript and I am using it to display the pdf to the user by:

```
document.location.href = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' +data;
```

which opens the file in a new window (it works in all browsers except IE as it has url restrictions) and the file is not downloadable in all browsers. IE is the primary browser for testing my application so this is a big issue.

Option of using a backend technology like Java to create a file and send it as the response is ruled out as I have an ABAP backend and it can give me only the bytestream. Many suggested using jsPdf but jsPdf creates the content from javascript (like setting line by line info and formatting) and uses it. But as I already have all the data and formatting I need I am not able to use it.

Here is the question I asked for byte conversion and display of pdf in the webpage, that got answered, for additional info:
[How to convert Hexadecimal Byte stream in the form of string to actual bytestream in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131789/how-to-convert-hexadecimal-byte-stream-in-the-form-of-string-to-actual-bytestrea)

I have done my best in searching for the solution but couldn't able to find one yet.

Comment: is it not possible  to call java method from jvascript?and pass `data` to it from there you can download pdf file. using `File Class`

Comment: I dont have Java backend that is the problem. I have only abapbackend, that gives me only the byte stream.

Answer (score 0):

it may help you try this way put pdf in the zip file, why zip? because The only way to make a pdf force download is by placing it in a .zip ,browser will get identify the things what to do with it   [link  here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/download-using-jquery)

[example here to make zip file download with the pdf](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/js/create-zip-file-javascript/)